# recoloring image using GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick, colormatrix

I tryed to recolor an image by using GraphicsMagick. In addition I used the 'gm' node.js package to write a little script. The main goal was to leave white as it is and just change the other colors.

Traget-RGB is (38, 250, 5)

The colormatrix I used look like this:

```
1 0.15 0.15   
0.98 1 0.98   
0.02 0.02 1
```

My calculation of the other values are:

```
38 / 255 = 0.15  
250 / 255 = 0.98  
5 / 255 = 0.02
```

The little script I wrote looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gm = require('gm');
gm('./input/image.png')
  .recolor("1 0.15 0.15 , 0.98 1 0.98  , 0.02 0.02 1")
  .write('./output/image.png', function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('done');
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

My thought was the one on diag do nt touches the white value and the other values where chaged to the target value. It has nearly the outcome that I was expecting but only nearly.